# Merge cells in R dataframe and download the result as an excel sheet

Tags: r, shiny, download

```
I have the following dataframe in R 


Sample=data.frame('A_P1_P2_2013_X_F'=c(1,2,20,50,90,200,NA), 
'A_P1_P2_2013_X_A'=c(1,2,20,50,90,NA,NA), 'A_P1_P2_2013_Y_F'=c(1,2,20,50,90,200,NA), 
'A_P1_P2_2013_Y_A'=c(1,2,20,50,90,200,NA), 'A_P1_P2_2013_Z_F'=c(1,2,20,50,90,200,NA), 
'A_P1_P2_2013_Z_A'=c(1,2,20,50,90,200,NA),"G_P1_O1_2013_X_F"=c(1,2,20,50,90,200,NA), 
 "G_P1_O1_2013_X_A"=c(1,2,20,50,90,200,NA), "G_P1_O1_2013_Y_F"=c(1,2,20,50,90,200,NA), 
 "G_P1_O1_2013_Y_A"=c(1,2,20,50,90,200,NA),"G_P1_O1_2013_Z_F"=c(1,2,20,50,90,200,NA), 
 "G_P1_O1_2013_Z_A"=c(1,2,20,50,90,200,NA))
```

I have subject the dataframe to the following processes in my code

```
Sample_head<-Sample[1,]##SPLIT INTO 2 Parts

Sample_head<-data.frame(Sample_head, check.names = FALSE)

Sample_head[1,]<-colnames(Sample_head)##FILL WITH COLUMN NAMES

Sample_head3<-rbind(Sample_head, Sample_head, Sample_head, Sample_head, Sample_head, 
Sample_head)###CREATE a dataframe with 6 rows
```

Now I have run the following functions to extract selected values using lapply

```
   splitter1<-function(x){strsplit(x , split = "_")[[1]][1] }
   splitter2<-function(x){strsplit(x , split = "_")[[1]][2] }
   splitter3<-function(x){strsplit(x , split = "_")[[1]][3] }
   splitter4<-function(x){strsplit(x , split = "_")[[1]][4] }
   splitter5<-function(x){strsplit(x , split = "_")[[1]][5] }
   splitter6<-function(x){strsplit(x , split = "_")[[1]][6] }
```

The above functions are applied to the

```
  Sample_head3[1,]<-lapply(Sample_head3[1,],splitter1 )
  Sample_head3[2,]<-lapply(Sample_head3[2,],splitter2 )
  Sample_head3[3,]<-lapply(Sample_head3[3,],splitter3 )
  Sample_head3[4,]<-lapply(Sample_head3[4,],splitter4 )
  Sample_head3[5,]<-lapply(Sample_head3[5,],splitter5 )
  Sample_head3[6,]<-lapply(Sample_head3[6,],splitter6 )
```

Next we combine Sample_head3 with Sample as follows

```
   Combo_Dataset<-rbind(Sample_head3,Sample )
```

The above steps have Yielded the following dataframe

[image]

I would like to obtain the following result in R and donload that result as an excel sheet[image]

How do I get this result  and download the same in R. I request someone to point me in the right direction. The same needs to be downloaded using a shiny App also

Comment: You can't merge cells in a R dataframe. But you can create a `xlsx` file with merged cells with the help of the `openxlsx` package.

Comment: Ok. But Does it allow one to download the excel after generating it in a shiny App.

Comment: For sure. You can download any file you create in a Shiny app (see `?shiny::downloadHandler`).

Comment: Thank you. Will give this a try and feeling encouraged that it should be doable